# How to open Vim session in a separate equivalently-structured directory?

Tags: git, vim

Here is a simplified example of my situation:

Say I have the following directory:

```
foo/
-- dir1/
-- dir2/
---- file1.txt
---- file2.txt
...
```

Additionally, I have another directory, let's call `bar/`, that has almost the exact same directory structure (e.g. the same git repository, but a different work tree, such as from executing `git worktree ...`).

I have lots of open files from within `foo/`, but I want to have the equivalently-named files within `bar/` open instead. I came across the Vim command, `:mksession`, that allows me to save a Vim session to reopen later, but it always reopens the files from within `foo/`, and not from within `bar/`.

Is there some way to save a Vim session, such that it would be possible to open it in another equivalently-structured directory?

Answer (score 2):

Possible is, but not with the VIM standard. If you open the session file, you will see that the VIM saves the path to the files. You can make a script (or running a command) that replaces `foo` by `bar`.

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' foo_session.vim  > bar_session.vim
```